# C++ with MinGW : ignored type qualifier on cast result type : but which qualifier is ignored?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, static-cast, qualifiers

I have abstract class `A` and derived class `B` that publicly inherits from `A`.

I pass a `const` pointer to a `const A` to a function. In this function I `static_cast` this to a `const` pointer to a `const B` and get the error `type qualifiers ignored on cast result type` (because we use `-Werror=ignored-qualifiers`).

What can be so wrong here ? I have all `const` qualifiers required, seems to me.

```
void foo(const A* const pA)
{
    const B* const pB = static_cast<const B* const>(pA); // Error
   
    // ... use pB ...
}
```

Edit : using `dynamic_cast` instead solves it. Why though ?

Comment: you probably want to use `static_cast<const B* const>(pA)`, cast to **B**

Comment: @jbachmann Yes my mistake. That's not the actual issue. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level qualifier. That is, the second one here: `static_cast<const B* const>(pA)`.

The cast returns a pointer prvalue, and (non-class non-array) prvalues [can't have cv-qualifiers](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2), so `const` is silently ignored.

Comment: But here both `A` and `B` are class so the non-class requirement doesn't seem to be satisfied. Did i miss something?

Comment: @user12002570 The cast returns a pointer (it doesn't matter if it's a pointer to class or not).

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that the warning/error was not due to the use of `static_cast` but due to the use of its result to initialize `pB`.

Comment: @user12002570 A lone cast warns too: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YMKhcfaP7

Comment: I'm new to such high-level C++ concepts but - why does the `dynamic_cast` work then ? Does it not also produce a prvalue ?

Comment: @Charles Looks like a compiler bug/defect to me, both should warn since they have the same issue.

Comment: Hm understood. Real solution is to remove the second `const` in the templace of `static_cast` anyways no ?

Comment: @Charles Yeah. It doesn't cause any issues, just has no effect.

Comment: I'm guessing that whoever introduced `-Werror=ignored-qualifiers` in our project didn't do it just because of this one.